# deployment error with nextjs and contentful

Tags: reactjs, next.js, vercel, contentful

How do I troubleshoot this problem this deployment issue? I am following this tutorial. My node_modules and .next are ignored and not pushed to github. It works locally but can't seem to deploy. I have supplied both the component code as well as the page it's exported on. Let me know if you can see what I am missing.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V4SVNleMitE

deployment errors

```
Error occurred prerendering page "/components/BlogPosts". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
TypeError: Cannot read property 'fields' of undefined
    at BlogPosts (/vercel/path0/.next/server/chunks/130.js:39:12)
    at d (/vercel/path0/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:33:498)
    at bb (/vercel/path0/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:36:16)
    at a.b.render (/vercel/path0/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:42:43)
    at a.b.read (/vercel/path0/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:41:83)
    at Object.exports.renderToString (/vercel/path0/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:52:138)
    at Object.renderPage (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:673:46)
    at Object.defaultGetInitialProps (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:315:51)
    at Function.getInitialProps (/vercel/path0/.next/server/pages/_document.js:645:16)
    at Object.loadGetInitialProps (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/shared/lib/utils.js:69:29)
Error occurred prerendering page "/Posts". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
```

component

```
export default function BlogPosts({post }) {
   
   const {title, information,slug , thumbnail} = post.fields
    
    return (
        <div>
        
      
            <div className='container w-50 h-25 mt-4'>
                <Image
                    className='nav' 
                    src={'https:' + thumbnail.fields.file.url}
                    width={thumbnail.fields.file.details.image.width}
                    height={thumbnail.fields.file.details.image.height}
                />
            </div>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <h4 className=''>{title}</h4>
                    <Link href={'/contentslug/' + slug}>
                        <a className='btn btn-primary text-white'>Read more</a>
                    </Link>
                </div>
            
            </div>
      
          
        </div>
    )
}
```

page

```
import {createClient} from 'contentful'
import BlogPosts from './components/BlogPosts'
import Nav from './components/Nav'
import Logo from './components/Logo'


export async function getStaticProps() {

  const client = createClient({
    space: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_CONTENTFUL_ID,
    accessToken: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_CONTENTFUL_TOKEN,
  })

const res = await client.getEntries({content_type: 'posts'})

return {
  props: {
    posts: res.items ,
    revalidate: 1
  }
}


}



export default function Home({posts}) {
 console.log(posts);
  
  return (
    
    <div>
     <Logo/> 
    <Nav/>
    <div className="container text-center display-5">
   {posts.map(post => (
    <BlogPosts key={post.sys.id} post={post}/>
           
   ))}

</div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

ERROR code with template literals for env files.

```
NotFound: {
  "status": 404,
  "statusText": "Not Found",
  "message": "The resource could not be found.",
  "details": {},
  "request": {
    "url": "entries",
    "headers": {
      "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
      "Content-Type": "application/vnd.contentful.delivery.v1+json",
      "X-Contentful-User-Agent": "sdk contentful.js/9.1.5; platform node.js/v16.13.0; os Windows/10.0.19043;",
      "Authorization": "Bearer ...fined",
      "user-agent": "node.js/v16.13.0",
      "Accept-Encoding": "gzip"
    },
    "method": "get"
  },
  "requestId": "99bba793-33fb-43f7-b471-a09cda6e0801"
}
    at errorHandler (C:\Users\Owner\teacher-esl\node_modules\contentful\dist\contentful.node.js:3771:15)
    at Object.getEntries (C:\Users\Owner\teacher-esl\node_modules\contentful\dist\contentful.node.js:8431:79)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async getStaticProps (C:\Users\Owner\teacher-esl\.next\server\pages\Posts.js:34:15)
    at async renderToHTML (C:\Users\Owner\teacher-esl\node_modules\next\dist\server\render.js:387:20)
    at async C:\Users\Owner\teacher-esl\node_modules\next\dist\export\worker.js:273:36
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (C:\Users\Owner\teacher-esl\node_modules\next\dist\trace\trace.js:74:20)
info  - Generating static pages (35/35)

> Build error occurred
Error: Export encountered errors on following paths:
        /Posts
        /components/BlogPosts
    at C:\Users\Owner\teacher-esl\node_modules\next\dist\export\index.js:493:19
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (C:\Users\Owner\teacher-esl\node_modules\next\dist\trace\trace.js:74:20)
    at async C:\Users\Owner\teacher-esl\node_modules\next\dist\build\index.js:970:17
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (C:\Users\Owner\teacher-esl\node_modules\next\dist\trace\trace.js:74:20)
    at async C:\Users\Owner\teacher-esl\node_modules\next\dist\build\index.js:844:13
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (C:\Users\Owner\teacher-esl\node_modules\next\dist\trace\trace.js:74:20)
    at async Object.build [as default] (C:\Users\Owner\teacher-esl\node_modules\next\dist\build\index.js:82:25)
```

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue when running `next build && next start` locally? Is the Contentful request returning the expected response inside `getStaticProps`?

Comment: locally npm run build shows me these errors - [    ] info  - Generating static pages (0/35)undefined
[==  ] info  - Generating static pages (28/35)
Error occurred prerendering page "/Posts". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
TypeError: Expected parameter accessToken

Comment: Are you [configuring the environment variables](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables) properly?

Comment: I don't think I am. I just switched it out and hard coded the values and the parameter issue went away. This is how the env is being processed  space: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_CONTENTFUL_SPACE,

Comment: despite hard coding i still received the error 'fields are undefined'

Comment: just put them in template literals and it threw a page 404 in npm run build. I've put the code above.

Answer (score -1):

It seems like the issue might be related to missing environmental variables. If you're deploying on Vercel, they offer an option to set environmental variables which your application might require to function correctly. Make sure to set the necessary variables in the Vercel dashboard, as this often resolves issues like the one you're facing. Give it a try, and hopefully, your problem will be resolved. If you need further assistance, feel free to ask!